# optimize.portfolio in R PorftolioAnalytics producing ony NA

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to optimize the edhec data with the following code, but getting only NAs as optimized weights

```
    library(openxlsx)
    library(PortfolioAnalytics)
    library(PerformanceAnalytics)
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(reshape2)
    library(ROI)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(car)
    library(quantmod)
    library(quadprog)
    library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
    require(ROI.plugin.glpk)
    require(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
    library(ROI.plugin.lpsolve)
    library(Rglpk)
    library(DEoptim)
    library(fGarch)
    library(pso)
    library(GenSA)
    library(nloptr)

    data(edhec)
    returns <- edhec[, 1:4]
    colnames(returns) <- c("CA", "CTAG", "DS", "EM")
    funds <- colnames(returns)

    portf_maxret <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
    portf_maxret <- add.constraint(portfolio=portf_maxret, type="return", return_target=.0075)
    portf_maxret<-add.objective(portfolio=portf_maxret, type="risk", name="StdDev")
    opt_maxret <- optimize.portfolio(R=returns, portfolio=portf_maxret,optimize_method="ROI", trace=TRUE)
```

The output of opt_maxret is

```
***********************************
PortfolioAnalytics Optimization
***********************************

Call:
optimize.portfolio(R = returns, portfolio = portf_maxret, optimize_method = "ROI", 
    trace = TRUE)

Optimal Weights:
  CA CTAG   DS   EM 
  NA   NA   NA   NA 

Objective Measure:
StdDev 
    NA
```

The same is happening with any data and happening only if I am trying to set `type="risk"`in `optimize.portfolio` i.e. trying to optimize the portfolio according to the risk associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

The propblem may be caused when you try to give the same name to your portfolios in the line:

```
portf_maxret<-add.objective(portfolio=portf_maxret, type="risk", name="StdDev")
```

Try to change `portf_maxret` into something else and use that as your portfolio name in optimization